# Multiply a BigNum with an plain integer

Tags: c, openssl, bignum

I have the following function:

```
BIGNUM * multiplyWithInt(BIGNUM *bn, int val){
  //Logic Here
}
```

What I try to do is to calculate the multiplication `bn*val`. For Multiplication according to documentation (given from command `man bn`) is the following:

```
int BN_mul(BIGNUM *r, BIGNUM *a, BIGNUM *b, BN_CTX *ctx);
```

As you can see I need to somehow toi convert the integer `val` into openssl's BIGNUM. How I can do that? One approach is to convert it as `unsigned char *` byte array and use the `BN_bin2bn` function but will that give me the desired functionality?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you're looking for is `BN_set_word`.  This assigns an `unsigned long` value to a `BIGNUM`.

```
BIGNUM *bn_val = BN_new();
BN_set_word(bn_val , val);
```

You can then pass `bn_val` and `bn` to `BN_mul`.

Comment: So in order to use it I just need to typecast my `int` into an `unsigned long` right?

Comment: @DimitriosDesyllas No need to cast.  The value will get converted automatically.  Note however that you can't use negative values.